# mask data fields in crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, dataset, data-masking

I am using crystal reports with vb.net. i have used wizard mode to create crystal report. In my report , there is employees data containing some confidential data too, that need to be masked for some users. how can i achieve this ? i.e only super admin can see all the data , for other(managers,finance) users, it will show masked. Like 0343-3434-34  will be ********34.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom functions in crystal reports. Get your value and simply replace it by the pattern you want. 
Visit these Links, hope it will help you
http://www.crystalreportsbook.com/Forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=19935 
http://scn.sap.com/community/crystal-reports/blog/2013/09/27/simplify-task-with-custom-function